# How to make `pulse-momentary-highlight-region` stop highlighting after 1 second?

Tags: osx

When I do `pulse-momentary-highlight-region`, 
the highlight stays till I press any key.

(I'm on macOS `emacs -nw`.)

How can I make the pulse to go away after a short while?

Comment: Maybe see if you see the same thing when starting with `emacs -Q` (no init file). If you do, consider posting a step-by-step recipe to repro it, in a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Answer (score 2):

Type `M-x find-library RET pulse RET` and have a peek at the variables defined with `defcustom` and `defvar` -- you can use `isearch` ....

How about customizing the following *three* variables?:

`pulse-iterations`:  "Number of iterations in a pulse operation."  [The default value is **10**.]

`pulse-delay`:  "Delay between face lightening iterations."  [The default value is **.03**.]

`pulse-flag`:  "Whether to use pulsing for momentary highlighting. ..."  [The default value is determined by the function `(pulse-available-p)`.]  The doc-string is semi-lengthy and has been truncated here for simplicity purposes.

Comment: pulse-available-p is nil for me

Comment: It looks like the function depends on the background of the `default` face:  `(condition-case nil (let ((v (color-values (face-background 'default)))) (numberp (car-safe v))) (error nil))`.  I would suggest setting the variable with a `t` and see if that gives you the desired result:  `(setq pulse-flag t`).

Comment: In addition, also check to see whether your `default` face has a background color that is recognized by your setup; e.g., that you did not make a typo in the hex or English name of the color; and, that your setup can take advantage of the color you have selected.  Try using something simple, like a "yellow" or "blue" background to do some troubleshooting ....